# sql query to find difference in two fields

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a sql server 2008 db  and focussed on two specific columns in a table of over 300 million records. I wanted to find duplicate records which the table has but disinguish from this result set how many and if any of the duplicates have a different field 2.
eg.

field 1:   idUrl
field 2:   assignedId

so for duplicates of course:

```
SELECT [idUrl]
       ,[assignedId]
FROM [Feeds].[dbo].[LogFeed]
group by idUrl, assignedId
having COUNT(entryId) > 1
order by entryid desc
```

So I want to find records where for any duplicates of idUrl are there any records where assignedId is not the same for the duplicate idUrls.

eg

```
 idUrl            assignedID
 www.google.com       10
 www.google.com       10
 www.google.com       10
 www.google.com        7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can write in so many ways  i am giving the sample  try this one

DECLARE @table table (idUrl varchar(100),assignedID int)
INSERT INTO @table 
values('www.google.com',       10),
 ('www.google.com',       10),
 ('www.google.com' ,      10),
 ('www.google.com' ,       7)

```
SELECT idUrl, COUNT ( Distinct AssignedID )   FROM @table 
Group By idUrl Having COUNT( Distinct AssignedID ) > 1
```